# Creating a script that checks the amount of files in a folder and if different then do something in windows?

Tags: vb.net, file, timer, automation

what language would be useful to make a program that looks in a directory and saves the amount of files inside of it as a variable then have it check if the variable does not equal what it was originally when it counted then run a script. since i have a folder that adds a new file to the directory every time something is changed i want a script to run that just runs an exe.

I have no idea on where to get started, if i should make a vb.net app thats a timer that runs every so often and does this for me. please help!!!

Thank you so much. Sorry I included no code I'm not expecting code in return i just need ideas on how i would plan this or go about doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into this class for watching updates into a directory and taking action against various types of updates

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx